# Django collectstatic does not use the path specified by STATIC_ROOT

Tags: django, deployment

In settings.py, I set the STATIC_ROOT as below:

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/files/'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'uploads'

when running the command:
python3 manage.py collectstatic

it works perfectly in my local development environment, it created a folder staticfiles, then collected all the files as expected, but when deploying the code on digitalOcean, it gives the error that says:

```
......

for entry in os.scandir(path):

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/kevin/myproject/static'
```

I set the path with BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles',
why it points to the  BASE_DIR / 'static'

the path and folder: BASE_DIR / 'static' was use by

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / 'static'
]

got so confused, debug it for a couple of days, it works in my local machine but not in production. any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the directory in `STATICFILES_DIRS` exist in your repo and is it located at `/home/kevin/myproject/static` when deployed on your server?

Comment: add your main projects urls.py file